# Delphi: what component is (TDockTabSet ?) and how to work with it?

Tags: delphi, tabs, vcl, tpagecontrol

[image]

Is this TDockTabSet for Delphi (highlighted)? Or an other component? How to work with it. I want to use it instead of TPageControl but with the same functionality - like Tab Sheets.

One more picture: http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/asg58.asp

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not `TDockTabSet`. As part of the Windows GUI it's clearly not a Delphi component.  What's more it is quite different in functionality.

What you have highlighted is a page control with the tabs at the bottom.  In Delphi terms it is `TabPosition=tpBottom`.

Comment: Is there a way to make those Tabs?

Comment: You want triangular tabs? I think you have to draw them yourself. Neither Aero nor classic look like that.

Comment: Yes, please, if you can help :)

Comment: @David But what is this Chinese example showing then http://www.ipentec.com/document/document.aspx?page=delphi2005-docktabset ? I don't see this guy using some other components...

Comment: Why do you want triangular tabs? They are very non-standard. Anyway, if that's what you want just draw them yourself.

Comment: you can probably use the source of some of the components you have discovered as a guide to owner drawing the page control.

Comment: @maxfax - Delphi has triangular tabs with the `TTabSet` component. Documentation states it's for backward compatibility and discourages its use. D2007 IDE uses them under the editor window (Code/Design/History), don't know about never versions...

Comment: I find it interesting that is described as being there for backwards compatibility... It's used as the basis for all of Delphi's docking tabs (although with it's style set to "Modern Popout").

Answer (score 1):

There is a Delphi control that looks like it: TTabSet with TabPosition = tpBottom. It will give you triangular tabs like in the picture. It is actually used by the RAD Studio and Delphi IDE too (below the editor/designer).

Answer (score 0):

Great example here [Using the TDockTabSet component](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33446)

Comment: TDockTabSet is a diffrent thing. It is TPageControl